# ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined error when doing query.

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Here's the query:

```
select STOCKS.STOCKNO, STOCKS.DESCRIPTION, ORDERITEMS.QTYORD
from STOCKS
left join ORDERITEMS
on STOCKS.STOCKNO = ORDERITEMS.STOCKNO 
WHERE STOCKNO !=(Select STOCKNO from ORDERITEMS where ORDERNO='1' or ORDERNO='2')
ORDER BY STOCKNO
/
```

Here's the error:

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined for every stock item..
```

Ive done the join but for the 1st query but for the 2nd query which is

```
WHERE STOCKNO !=(Select STOCKNO from ORDERITEMS where ORDERNO='1' or ORDERNO='2')
```

Question is to display STOCKS, DESCRIPTION and Quantity Ordered including the stocks
that no order has been placed for them so far.

Comment: Disambiguate it by selecting a table.  The column appears in both.

Answer (score 3):

Which stock number ?

```
WHERE STOCKNO
```

Either `STOCKS.STOCKNO` or `ORDERITEMS.STOCKNO`

Comment: both are the same, so inorder to find out stock which hasnt been ordered. the stockno is within the orderitems table already.

Comment: Have you told Oracle that ?

Comment: im sure the query says that

Answer (score 2):

Try to use aliases as below and replace `!=` with `not in`:

```
select S.STOCKNO, S.DESCRIPTION, O.QTYORD
from STOCKS S
left join ORDERITEMS O on S.STOCKNO = O.STOCKNO 
WHERE S.STOCKNO not in (select O2.STOCKNO  
                        from ORDERITEMS O2 
                        where O2.ORDERNO='1' or O2. ORDERNO='2')
ORDER BY S.STOCKNO
/
```

Comment: tried the query but now its showing SQL> select S.STOCKNO, S.DESCRIPTION, O.QTYORD
  2  from STOCKS S
  3  left join ORDERITEMS O
  4  on S.STOCKNO = O.STOCKNO
  5  WHERE S.STOCKNO !=(select O2.STOCKNO FROM ORDERITEMS O2 WHERE O2.ORDERNO= '1' OR O2.ORDERNO='2')
  6  ORDER BY S.STOCKNO;
WHERE S.STOCKNO !=(select O2.STOCKNO FROM ORDERITEMS O2 WHERE O2.ORDERNO= '1' OR O2.ORDERNO='2')
                   *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: @JasonKemeys Try to change `!=` to `not in` as above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use aliases.

```
select 
    s.stockno, 
    s.description, 
    o.qtyord
from stocks s
left join orderitems o
    on s.stockno = o.stockno 
where s.stockno not in ( select stockno from orderitems where orderno in ( '1', '2' ) )
order by s.stockno
;
```

In particular, you need to use `where s.stockno not in <subquery>`.

Comment: Why avoid != in favour of <> ?